# Date and time in PHP pagination script - slight problems

Tags: php, database, pagination, phpmyadmin

I have an events calendar written in PHP, with the following pagination script that I obtained from a free PHP site.
This is the basic script (entitled PmcPagination.php):

http://pastebin.com/f7c5a4a90
(linked here for convenience, too lengthy to post in full!)

It works to the extent that it shows all events - but the dates do not tally with the database, and as such are all listed as the following:
Event 1 on January 1st, 1970 - 1:00am "Family Event" Set Reminder
Event 2 on January 1st, 1970 - 1:00am "Historical Event" Set Reminder
... and so on, for the next 20, 30, 40 records.

What should I do to fix this date/time error in the code? It's rendering OK ... **for now** but the date/time thing is proving tricky to fix.

Research on Google and various PHP sites did not help, so where has this gone wrong?
(The code isn't my own, but an adapted version of someone else's!)

Comment: Where does `airdate` ever get set?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/f59b1fab4 - I changed it to eventdate but still get January 1st, 1970 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything on a date of January 1st, 1970 is probably a date of 0. Check to make sure that the value is not 0 and is a valid integer.